# How can I create a new matrix via replacement in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrix:

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
C=[0 0 2; 0 0 1; 0 0 8]
```

I want to keep nonzero values of C and create D. Then, replace the zero elements with A matrix.

So D should be:

```
D=[1 2 2; 4 5 1; 7 8 8]
```

I try this code:

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
C=[0 0 2; 0 0 1; 0 0 8]
T=A(C==0)
R=sparse(T)
K=find(sparse(C))
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
D = A;
D(C~=0) = C(C~=0);
```

Answer (score 3):

drorco's answer is the right way to do it, but there is a one-liner that I couldn't resist:

```
D = ~C.*A + ~~C.*C;
```

Comment: We love one liners too much, don't we?

Comment: indeed! but it's an addiction that we have to fight.

Answer (score 2):

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
C=[0 0 2; 0 0 1; 0 0 8];
D=A;
inds=find(C~=0);
D(inds)=C(inds)

D =

 1     2     2
 4     5     1
 7     8     8
```